# Docker Compose with NGINX proxy pass thru not working

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

Following is my Docker Compose file & NGINX conf file.

The application seems to work and NGINX is also up, but the proxy_pass setting doesn't seem to work properly.

> File
> **docker-compose.yaml**

```
networks:
  webapp:

services:
 
  web:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./data/ntemplates:/etc/nginx/templates
      - ./webapp.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/webapp.conf
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - webapp

  pyweb:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    networks:
      - webapp

  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    networks:
      - webapp
```

> File **webapp.conf**

```
server { 
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
       proxy_pass "http://pyweb_1:5000/";
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

}
```

Service pyweb is working if properly if directly accessed by http://pyweb_1:5000

I created this app based on docker getting started [page](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/)
For completeness below are other files and seems to be working just fine.

> File **Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
WORKDIR /code
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run"]FROM python:3.7-alpine
WORKDIR /code
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

> File **requirement.txt**

```
flask
redis
```

> File **app.py**

```
import time

import redis
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
cache = redis.Redis(host='redis', port=6379)

def get_hit_count():
    retries = 5
    while True:
        try:
            return cache.incr('hits')
        except redis.exceptions.ConnectionError as exc:
            if retries == 0:
                raise exc
            retries -= 1
            time.sleep(0.5)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    count = get_hit_count()
    return 'Hello World! I have been seen {} times.\n'.format(count)
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://serverfault.com/a/904136/383073

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

You're currently not using the nginx configuration. I didn't read carefully your docker-compose file. You can fix it by mapping the webapp.conf on /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf. e.g.

```yaml
services:
 
  web:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./data/ntemplates:/etc/nginx/templates
      - ./webapp.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      - pyweb
    networks:
      - webapp
```

---

There are 2 issues:

- you don't know what container name will be used by docker-compose
- you don't know the order used to start the containers

docker-compose allows you to solve the first issue in 2 ways:

- define a `container_name` subsection
- use the service name

This means that you can simply use `proxy_pass "http://pyweb:5000/";` in your nginx setup

The second issue can be fixed by adding a `depends_on` subsection in the nginx service. e.g.

```yaml
services:
 
  web:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./data/ntemplates:/etc/nginx/templates
      - ./webapp.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/webapp.conf
    depends_on:
      - pyweb
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - webapp
```

Nevertheless, the `depends_on` might not be enough since it does not check the service status but it only make sure that the docker service is started (as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on)).

You'll need to find another way to monitor if the service is actually started.